# Print table name inside a query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sp-msforeachtable

I want to execute a query on all tables but I need to inspect results.
If I do:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 
'
DBCC CHECKIDENT(''?'', NORESEED)
'
```

The results looks like:

> Checking identity information: current identity value '35', current column value '35'.
>       DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
>       Msg 7997, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>       'DocumentsJobPositions' does not contain an identity column.

And so on. Sometimes it's ok sometimes I need to make some fixes, so I need the name of each table for each query!

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 
'
print ''?''
DBCC CHECKIDENT(''?'', NORESEED)
'
```

Comment: Your answer deserves ~200 upvotes. I can't thank you enough.